# why isnt my mysqli query returning any rows

Tags: php, mysql

So i'm trying to make a login system and its not working because every time I test the number of rows via this code:

```
$username=$_POST['username']; 
$password=$_POST['password']; 
$username = stripslashes($myusername);
$password = stripslashes($mypassword);
$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($username);
$password = mysqli_real_escape_string($password);
$result=mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT * FROM users  WHERE username='$username'");
$count=mysqli_num_rows($result);
if($count==1){
```

but everytime I run it it doesn't return 1, I don't even know how to check what its returning and when I remove $username's '' marks it comes up invalid query

Im using PHP 5.4.4-14, Mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.31, for debian-linux-gnu (armv7l) using readline 6.2, and Apache/2.2.22 (Debian)

Comment: mysqli_real_escape_string needs the connection...http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should really switch to prepared statements instead of injecting your variables directly in the query, but you problem is caused by [`mysqli_real_escape_string()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php). That function needs two parameters, the first one being the mysqli connection.

Comment: what do you mean 'prepared statements?'

Comment: @user1895629 I prefer to use PDO, but for mysqli: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php. Check the examples, a statement is prepared using placeholders where your variables should be and then you bind your variables to the placeholders, eliminating the need for escaping.

Comment: @user1895629 he means [`mysqli_prepare()`](http://php.net/mysqli-prepare).